# How to delete multiple files from an MTP device?

Tags: windows-7, media-player, mtp

How may I delete multiple selected files from an MTP device in a single operation?

Though Delete on a single file succeeds, on multiple files it fails, saying **No such interface is supported**, as here:

[image]